# Click on button and fill elements inside a Table using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have `html table` that both include `button` and `fill form` as follows

```
<table class="configTbl" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="_0" class="login_input_text">Username</span>&nbsp;:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="un" value="admin" class="configF1" id="txtUserName" size="20" maxlength="31" autocomplete="off">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span id="_0" class="login_input_text">Password</span>&nbsp;:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="pw" id="txtLoginPwd" class="configF1" maxlength="64" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="hidden" name="rd" value="/uir/dwrhome.htm">
                <input type="hidden" name="rd2" value="/uir/loginpage.htm">
                <input type="hidden" name="Nrd" value="1"> &nbsp;
                <input type="hidden" name="Nlmb">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="submitBg_new">
                <input value="Login" id="_0" class="submit" onmouseover="this.className = 'submitHover'" onmouseout="this.className = 'submit'" title="Login" type="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the main issue is filling the forms and click button I have used following codes for filling password

```
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"txtLoginPwd")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="txtLoginPwd"]')))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'pw')))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@name="pw"]')))
```

and even filling forms in table

```
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((\
By.XPATH,"//form[@class='configTbl']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]")))
```

or

```
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, \
###"//td[@class='user_type' and text()='real']//following-sibling::td[2]//button[contains(., 'Delete')]")))
#'//table[@class="configTbl"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a[@id="txtLoginPwd"]')))
'//table[@class="tableTest"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/descendant::a[@id="txtLoginPwd"]')))
```

but it has not been working for me.I get timeout error

> TimeoutException: Message:
> Stacktrace:
> Backtrace:

in addition, clicking on login button has been difficult for me what should i do?

Comment: Can you share a link to that page and ALL your Selenium code? Currently this question is missing too much details and can't be debugged

Comment: what was the error? Please post error stack as well.

Comment: It has not been able to find it and it shows timeout

Comment: @RF1991, may be element is inside `iframe` or under shadow-root element? Please have a look.

Comment: @KunduK thanks for your time, it was solved by using frame and switching method